# JDK, JSP and JSTL compability list/table

Tags: jsp, jstl, compatibility

I've been working with STS and keep getting compatibility errors between JDK, JSP and JSTL versions.

Does anyone know of a list/table which provides this information?  I've been looking and looking but cannot find it.

Comment: I think you'll find [Apache Tomcat - Which Version Do I Want?](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) helpful.

Comment: Next time just copypaste and ask about the exact error you faced instead of asking an overly broad question.

Comment: Thanks Elliot! This is exactly what I was looking for!  :-)